# Is it possible to connect to a WiFi network using the router's MAC address and not the broadcasted SSID on Android?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, wifi-hotspot, android-10

Assuming that there are many hotspots broadcasting the same SSID, is it possible to "force" my Android phone to connect to a specific network by using a unique identifier, for example the MAC address of the broadcasting router?

What I'm looking for is a solution without the need of third party software. I'm currently using Android 10 on Xiaomi MIUI 12, but I'm open to hear any answer including other Android versions or mobile manufacturers.